# jQuery for loop not recognizing variable in closure in Drupal behavior...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Can anyone tell me why this might not work

```
Drupal.behaviors.toggleGroups = {
  attach:function(context, settings) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      $('#edit-group-' + i.toString() + '-toggle').unbind('click').click(function(i) {
        $('#category-' + i.toString()).slideToggle();
      });
    }
  }
};
```

But this ugly thing works just fine

```
Drupal.behaviors.toggleGroups = {
  attach:function(context, settings) {
    $('#edit-group-1-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-1').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#edit-group-2-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-2').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#edit-group-3-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-3').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#edit-group-4-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-4').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#edit-group-5-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-5').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#edit-group-6-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-6').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#edit-group-7-toggle').unbind('click').click(function() {
      $('#category-7').slideToggle();
    });
  }
};
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like "while selector returns result do something" - the problem is that I need the incremented number, and each click will toggle a separate div.  It possible I'm just thinking about it all wrong, but regardless, I can't figure out why what I have isn't valid...

And while your at it, any advise on the jQuery once() method so I don't have to unbind/bind the click handler would also be appreciated...

THANK YOU!

Comment: There is no need to use `.toString()` on the numbers (`i`).

Comment: If you use 2 common classes instead of a thousand ids you can forget about for loops and closures.

Comment: @elclanrs care to elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common case of "iditis". If you use two common classes everything will be much easier to manipulate. Remove ids and add classes, `edit-group-toggle` and `category`, then you can grab their corresponding targets by index:

```
attach: function( context, settings ) {
  $('.edit-group-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.category').eq( $(this).index() ).slideToggle();
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you!  I didn't know about eq either, obviously, but this was exactly what I needed.  I did need to traverse the dom a bit to get to a structure with suitable indexes thanks to D7 Froms API and my own idiosyncrasy, but yes, iditis was a correct diagnosis!

Answer (score 3):

**Classic closure issue..**

Try this

```
Drupal.behaviors.toggleGroups = {
  attach:function(context, settings) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      (function(num){
         $('#edit-group-' + num + '-toggle')
                                    .unbind('click').click(function(num) {
            $('#category-' + num).slideToggle();
         });
      })(i)
    }
  }
};
```

By the time the functions are assigned the variable **i** shares the same memory location.
SO it will always point to the **last instance of i**

Comment: Could you explain why this works? Also, do you really need the `toString()`s?

Comment: @Blender .. We are executing the function immediately for that particular instance of i .. So the event will be bound the current iteration rather than the last instance of the iteration

Comment: @Blender the `(function (num) { ... })(i)` part means `execute this function now and use the current value of i as its argument`

Comment: Well, it looks really good, and is indeed fascinating, but I can't say I'm getting it to work: `attach:function(context, settings) {
        for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
          (function(num) {
            $('#edit-group-' + num + '-toggle').unbind('click').click(function(num) {
              $('#category' + num).slideToggle();
            });
          })(i);
        }
      }` - this is producing the same non-result as my loop.

Comment: Nope - correcting the $('#category' + num) selector to the correct $('#category-' + num) didn't help either.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: AH!  So by attaching the function as I was, it was only executing on the click event, by which time, the for loop was long, long over - correct?  I ended up using the solution below, as it was a better fit for my needs, and I was unable to untangle my rats-nest enough to make this function - but I do appreciate the feedback. Thank you!